# JavaScript literal keys

Tags: javascript

If only JavaScript strings and numbers can be object literal keys can someone explain why this works in the console?

```
var obj = {null: 0, true: 1, false: -1}
> Object {null: 0, true: 1, false: -1}
obj.null
> 0
obj.true
> 1
obj.false
> -1
```

Comment: objects keys are converted to a string

Comment: @DanielA.White Not here. See my answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your keys aren't `null` or `true` but `"null"` and `"true"`.

Note that **this isn't a conversion**. The `{key:value}` notation is another way to write `{"key":value}`. There's no conversion happening in keys in the [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals) notation, the quotes are simply optional when the key is a valid JavaScript identifier (which is the case for `null`).

It's very different from what would have happened if you'd use the brackets notation (i.e. `obj[true]=1`) : Anything that is not a string is converted to a string in order to be used as key in that case.

This distinction isn't obvious here but it may matter otherwise : you'd get something very different with

```
var a = {eval:1}; // no conversion, the key is "eval"
```

and

```
var a = {};
a[eval] = 1; // conversion, the key is eval.toString()
```

which would be the same (without cross-browser guarantee) as

```
var a = {"function eval() { [native code] }":1};
```

while

```
var a = {true:1};
```

would be equivalent to

```
var a = {};
a[true] = 1;
```

Comment: Something interesting just happened. While drunk (Riesling if that matters) I first gave a very concise and clear answer which got to +7 almost instantly. Then I realized it was also *totally wrong* and I fixed it. Which made it less concise and stopped the upvotes... There's something to be learnt here...

Comment: You might want to use some other expression (number, object literal) instead of that `eval` function in your example